# How can I merge into one cell, all the non-zero values in a row each concatenated with the column header?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, concatenate

I hope this example is clear. I have played with `join` and `filter` but can't get the *Summary* field to display as below:

[image: Example]

Row 1 is a list of subjects.
Row 2 is a teacher's subject allocation (calculated from a lookup).
I want the Summary cell to simply work through each row, if there is a non-zero value in a cell, take that number and concatenate to the subject, then move on to the end of the list.

Happy to try a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following piece of code you can prepare the summary as you want.

### Code

```
function mySummary(header, range) {
  var output1 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var output2 = [];
    for(var j=0, jLen=range[0].length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var value = range[i][j];
      if(value != "" || value > 0) {
        output2.push(value + " " + header[0][j]);
      }     
    }
    output1.push([output2.sort().join(", ")]);
  }
  return output1;  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The custom function needs two parameters to work with: *header* & *range*. The first iteration (*var i=0*) handles the rows and the second (*var j=0*) handles the columns. Each cell will be evaluated for empty (`""`) or non-zero (`> 0`) values. When either of them is `true`, the result is pushed into an intermediate array (`output2`). When the first row is completed, the combined result is sorted and joined and pushed into a new output array (`output1`), before starting with the second row.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Special Summary](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/102mBPj2Y-rg9ET5kd8WcBZ57ceVACyaSNgukrYTfAlw/edit?usp=sharing)**
Add the script under *Tools>Script editor* and press the save button.

Answer (score 1):

With the following formula you can do it as well.

### Formula

```
=JOIN(
   ", ",                                   ==> delimiter join
   TRANSPOSE(
     SORT(
       TRANSPOSE(                          ==> data sort  
         SPLIT(
           JOIN(                           ==> data for split
             ",",                          ==> delimiter join
             ARRAYFORMULA(
               IF(
                 A2:D2<>"",                ==> if statement
                 A2:D2 & " " & $A$1:$D$1,  ==> true statement 
                 ""                        ==> false statement
               )
             )
           ),
           ","                             ==> delimiter split
         )
       ),
       1,                                  ==> column index sort
       TRUE                                ==> ascending or descending
     )
   )
 )


 copy/paste
 =JOIN(", ",TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:D2<>"",A2:D2 & " " & $A$1:$D$1, ""))),",")),1,TRUE)))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Special Summary](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/102mBPj2Y-rg9ET5kd8WcBZ57ceVACyaSNgukrYTfAlw/edit?usp=sharing)**

### Note

The formula is quite long I would say. Adding other criteria will make it even longer. The advantage is the quick re-calculation of the result. A dis-advantage, despite the `ARRAYFORMULA`, is that it isn't possible to address the range as in the script version.